# Compilation Wall of Errors Seemingly Unrelated to .cpp

Tags: ros, compile, ros-kinetic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I've been writing a ROS publisher/subscriber node in C++ on ROS kinetic using a Navio2 board. When I attempt to compile, I don't get any syntax errors, but instead get a wall of errors involving dependencies, serializations, and whatnot:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/8c11d52bb03cfe8c9aa576086f57c2e2

Can anyone tell me what's going on? I'm new to ROS. Thanks

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300668/compilation-wall-of-errors-seemingly-unrelated-to-.cpp/) by [Old Meme](https://answers.ros.org/users/36982/old-meme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2018-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my CMakeLists.txt file, I added target_link_libraries(roscomm ${catkin_LIBRARIES}) and everything's working now

---

Originally posted by [Old Meme](https://answers.ros.org/users/36982/old-meme/) with karma: 40 on 2018-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-16**:
I should have asked you for your `CMakeLists.txt` before making assumptions about C++11.

I was under the impression you already had everything setup for linking, but checking #q300573 we see that you link against `catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS` there, which won't work.